# Regex: Testing for entire string

Tags: regex

I'm learning how to use regular expression, and I'm having some difficulties with this problem.

Suppose I input a number, and the input returns true for the whole number if the number contains at least one 7, but no 9s.

For example:
`123456789` should return false, and the input of `12345678` should return true for `12345678`.

What regular expression should be used for this?

I know the terms `7+` and `[^9]` are involved, but I'm not entirely sure how to make it return true for the entire number with those specific conditions (`7+[^9]` returns true with input `12345678` for 123456`78`9, when I want this to return true for `12345678`).

Sorry if I worded the question badly.

Comment: This page will let you test regular expressions against input: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like: `^[0-8]*7[0-8]*$`

Comment: I like it... it also returns true for 000007. Not sure how literal the "whole number" remark was meant to be.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Thank you. I've presented just a generic idea of how it might be. Of course, it may vary depending on the exact task and regexp dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a positive lookahead to assert at least one 7 in the number:

```
^(?=.*7)[0-8]++$
```

The first part `(?=.*7)` is a zero width assertion, it tests that there is at least one 7. It does this by asserting that the pattern `.*7` exists - i.e. anything followed by a 7.

The second part `[0-8]++` checks that all digits in the number are between 0-8. The `++` is a possessive match for one or more characters. So the number has to be at least one digit long.

**EDIT**

To deal with the comment by @AbsoluteƵERØ, if you want to ensure that the number is a real number, i.e. that the first digit is not zero, you can simply assert that too

```
^(?=.*7)(?!0)[0-8]++$
```